# Kotlin from IntelliJ: NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, intrinsics

Ever since I upgraded to Kotlin `1.1.0-rc-91` I have been receiving this exception when trying to run my app from IntelliJ.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at com.charlatano.Charlatano.main(Charlatano.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

It does, however, work when I build a JAR of the app and run it that way.

The entire app is hosted here: https://github.com/Jire/Charlatano

Specifically, I think it has something to do with my Gradle configuration: https://github.com/Jire/Charlatano/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167412

Comment: Confirming it is a duplicate, thanks @IRus for the solution!